# Booleans are all messed up

Tags: modeling

I want to unite 2 meshes into 1, by removing intersecting faces. But union is now doing this

[image]
[image]
Was there an update?

Comment: Also, intersect is doing what difference used to do.

Comment: If normals are not correct, the operation result may be different from what expected. Could you provide a file where the problem happens?

Comment: I tried recalculating normals

Answer (score 2):

### Apply scale and recalculate Normals

The selected object has a negative scale. Despite you see it light grey in the viewport, the faces are indeed flipped for the modifiers, as the object transformations are runned after them.

[image]

I would suggest to **apply the scale** in Object mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), than go to edit mode and **recalculate normals** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>).

[image]
[image]

Result:

[image]

Notice that the same result can be achieved by simply give to the X scale a positive value, but to avoid misbehavior in future operations is better to fix the scale once for all:

[image]