# Boolean glitch on object - Creates duplicate rather than subtracts

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a cube (on the right side of image) I wanted to slice out an oval from. No matter how I try it will NOT subtract. It actually creates a duplicate object (that what I wanted sliced) and JOINS that duplicate to the object it should have been sliced from. Annoying! **So** I created the same objects all over again and **it worked just fine** as you can see with the rectangular object on the left. So NBD. I just want some resolution as to WHY it won't work on the first dang object. Try it yourself. Blend file attached. (disregard the image behind the cube on the right side)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may want to see ..... http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44144/boolean-modifiers-are-not-working-correctly-on-this-mesh/44151#44151

Comment: You may find it helpful to you and others .... to delete the ancient file and replace it.  The incomplete boolean modifer dominates the discussion.

Comment: What ancient file The blend file or the picture?

Comment: People might open your blend file and look at settings that you say you have changed and corrected.  Do you want that?  Rhetorical Question.  But it would be a better use of our time to move onto new questions and ideas.

Comment: Image revised and new blend file added (however I did not hit apply in this document, so that anyone wanting to test it can duplicate the same issue and cleraly see ---IT DOES NOT work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Booleans are all messed up](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34711/booleans-are-all-messed-up) plus http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27675/boolean-difference-removes-wrong-part?rq=1 (in your case apply scale& rotation to the rectangle and recalculate normals)

Comment: As you stated I applied scale & rotation to the rectangle. And tried the operation again. It did the same thing. Again. I do not know what "recalculate normals" means or how to do that. But the answer right below stating "my normals looks okay" and "change the Y scale from -0.5 to 0.5 WORKED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to Union it will do the Difference and vice versa that's even though the normals look okay the object in fact is inverted on the Y axis look at the scale on the Y it reads -0.5 just change it to 0.5 and it will work as intended

Comment: EXACTLY! You nailed it! Such a simple thing it seems... Good catch. But now I'm not understanding how or why changing the Y axis on the scale from -0.5 to 0.5 effects this. What's a "normals" (that "look ok")?

Comment: @Marc normals are direction where the face is pointing ( facing ) , they should point outside the object, when you do boolean operation what is behind the faces is considered the inside , apparently the scale is taking in consideration so a negative scale means the the object was flipped inside out

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an object in the modifier.

[image]

The red color above indicates the object is incomplete.

You likely meant to do something like this below

[image]

Comment: Sorry. Yes.. I know I need to specifiy an object. I DID. Problem IS (and the reson why I provdided the blend file) is that even after specifying the object, hitting apply -- I got the results as described above. IT WILL NOT subtract. And yuet the very next test (on the left) it works fine.

Comment: You may find it helpful to delete the ancient file and replace it.